# Pagination a script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, status

I need to activate contacts in unsubscribed status in all subscriber in SFMC. This script works but i need to manage 100k rows. There are any way to paginate the script?

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
var dataExtensionName = "inserte DEname";
var dataExtension = DataExtension.Init(dataExtensionName);
var subscribersToUpdate = dataExtension.Rows.Lookup(["Status"], ["Unsubscribed"]); 

if (subscribersToUpdate.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < subscribersToUpdate.length; i++) {
        var sk = subscribersToUpdate[i].subscriberkey;
        if (sk) {
            var subscriber = Subscriber.Init(sk);
            var updateResult = subscriber.Update({
                "Status": "Active" 
            });

            // Opcional: Actualizar la Data Extension si necesitas marcar que el estado ha sido procesado
            // dataExtension.Rows.Update({ "Processed": "True" }, ["EmailAddress"], [email]);

            Write("Status updated for: " + sk + "<br>");
        }
    }
} else {
    Write("No subscribers to update.");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The maximum records of the lookup function can retrieve are 2000 records. Not mention that if you have too many records to update then soon you will hit the time out error in the automation.

If this is an one time update, I would recommend you extract the records you want to update into a CSV file (by SQL for example), change status to `Active` and then use import subscribers wizard in All subscribers that was written in this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_import_subscribers_from_file.htm&type=5).

Comment: The activity doesn't failed, run to many minutes and updates the ones it can. Not more than 2k but varies the volume. From my team doesn't recomended the import activity but i will try to update in this way. Thank you

Comment: @Magalí Why not? For a bulk operation like this case, I doubt if using SSJS is an effective way to finish it